# How to get inactive days from user's last logon time?

Tags: powershell

I need to export all inactive users in Office 365 with their inactive days.

I used `Get-MailboxStatistics` command, but using that I could get only last logon time but not inactive days.

Can anyone suggest command to get inactive days?

Comment: Can't you calculate the inactive days by figuring out the difference between last logon and the current date? You can get `get-date` to get the current time

Comment: What does "inactive days" mean?  Is it the number of days since last logon?  if so, you should simply be able to subtract the last logon date from the current date.  Does it mean something else?  Last time they sent an email, saved a document, etc?  This tool might help you:  [Office 365 Reporting Tool](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Office-365-Reporting-Tool-7987b4c2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct command to get inactive days. you can use New-TimeSpan command to get number of days. For eg, if last logon time stored in lastlogontime variable,

```
    $InactiveDays=(New-TimeSpan -Start $lastLogonTime).Days
```

Hope this might resolve your problem!!